# Formula for repeated cyclic counting variable?

Tags: counter

I am looking for a formula to achieve a specific type of counting for my code. This question has probably already been addressed, but I can't seem to find it, possibly because I'm not sure if I'm using the correct terminology to describe my problem.

But essentially, I am looking for a formula for a variable counter that loops through the following numbers:
1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 1 1 1....

Each number is repeated 3 times, with an increment of 1, and the cycle starts over on the 3rd 3. Or more generally, is there a generic formula that allows a repetition of numbers, say, x amount of times, between a min and max value, with an increment of y?

Answer (score 0):

Heres a function that can do what you want:

```
function repeatToX (x) {
  for (let i=1; i<=x; i++) {
    for (let j=0; j<3; j++) {
      console.log(i);
    }
  }
}

repeatToX(3);
```

The function will repeat a number starting from 1 up to the number provided as the paramerter (3 in this example). It does this by logging  the external for loop variable (i) while the internal for loop runs for as many times as you want that number repeated. We could make it even more flexible by running it like this:

```
function repeatToXYTimes (x, y) {
  for (let i=1; i<=x; i++) {
    for (let j=0; j<=y; j++) {
      console.log(i);
    }
  }
}

repeatToXYTimes(3, 3)
```

Now the numbers will go from 1 until x. And the number will repeat y amount of times.

Finally we have this one:

```
function repeatXTimes (x, min, max) {
  for (let i=min; i<=max; i++) {
    for (let j=0; j<=x; j++) {
      console.log(i);
    }
  }
}

repeatXTimes(3, 3, 5)
```

This one repeats x times from min to max.